# Rails form select from two options with a button - custom form implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a website where I want users to be able to select what type of user they are during the registration process.

Specifically, the implementation I want is to have two buttons on the signup page, one called "Seller" and one called "Buyer".

The user should be able to select only one button and once clicked, it should stay highlighted (I know this is just jquery so not the issue).

The selection should be stored in a column in my users model called :type.

It seems pretty straightforward, but the "f.select" form method seems to only implement a dropdown menu, so I am wondering how I can achieve this implementation of two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already going to use jQuery, you could add a hidden field for `type`, create 2 links and style them as buttons, and use jQuery to update the value of `type` when a user clicks one of the "buttons".